# Does Bootstrap work with vue3 or is it only working with vue2?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Wondering if bootstrap is working with vue3? Is it better to use vue 3 or stay with vue 2?

Comment: Bootstrap is a CSS framework and it's indepandant from any JS framework

Answer (score 2):

Pure bootstrap as a css framework is independent from vue version. Generally you can use any javascript framework with any css framerwok.

But there are libraries like:

https://bootstrap-vue.org/

where you can read:

> Built with Vue.js v2.6 and Bootstrap SCSS v4.6

and on link: https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3

> With the release of v2.23.0 you can now use BootstrapVue with migration build of Vue.js 3

so support of `bootstrap-vue` library for vue3 is limited but in future (`bootstrap-vue 3.0`) full support will be provided.

There are other libraries:

https://github.com/cdmoro/bootstrap-vue-3

described as

> BootstrapVue3 is an attempt to have BootstrapVue components in Vue3, Bootstrap 5, and typescript.

so you can try with this one. It has some bugs but is actively developed.